# how to enable logs for particular database in amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-rds

On my amazon RDS instance I have many databases. I just wanted to enable logs for a specific database.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The log enabling params are set in parameter group which applies to the whole server not DB-specific.

The closest solution would be to log everything and filter for the DB that you want.

For general_log:

- enable it in your parameter group: general_log = 1, log_output = TABLE
- have different DB access user for each DB
- query logs like this:

`select * from mysql.general_log where user_host like "DB1_user%"`